# How to buy more Azure DevOps pipelines build minutes?

Tags: azure-devops, azure, azure-pipelines

As mentioned on the [Azure DevOps official pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/), the plan provides 1 Free Microsoft-hosted CD/CI parallel job with up to 1800 minutes per month and 1 Free Self-hosted CD/CI parallel job with unlimited minutes per month.

When we exceed the limit of Microsoft-hosted minutes, what I do is configure a VM as the build agent. How can I buy more build minutes after exceeding this 1800 minutes, rather than launching VMs for agents by myself?

Answer (score 2):

You can set up billing in your Organization settings in DevOps

https://dev.azure.com/~your organization name~/_settings/billing

Comment: I'm on the billing page. What option extends build minutes? how much it costs?

Comment: It [appears to be](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/) $40/parallel job, each with unlimited minutes. I have not set up billing for myself so I don't know what that experience looks like.